# Raw SQL inside eloquent query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a users table, roles table and a user_role table.

```
User
id | name

Roles
id | title

User_Role
user_id | role_id
```

I need an eloquent query that finds if a user has all roles.

So far I have:

```
$userId = 1;
$role = array('admin', 'public');

$data = User::whereHas('roles', function($q) use ($role){

    $q->whereRaw($q->whereIn('title', $role)->count() .' = '.count($role));

})->find($userId);
```

But I get the error:

```
Unknown column user.id in where clause.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.
The query should return null if the user doesn't have the specified roles.

```
$userId = 1;
$role = array('admin', 'public');

$data = User::whereHas('roles', function($q) use ($role){

    $q->whereIn('title', $role);

}, '>=', count($role))->find($userId);
```